# Actualizar multiples objetos en DjangoRestFramework

Tags: django, rest, update, framework

Me encuentro con la necesidad de enviar al backend desde vue.js un array con una lista de objetos y desde Django actualizarlos todos.
En el caso de enviar solo un objeto puedo actualizarlo sin ningún problema. Copio mi view, serializer y modelo.

```
class ResponseReportFieldsUpdateAPiView(UserContextMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
queryset = ReportResponseSectionField.objects.all()
serializer_class = ReportResponseSectionFieldsSerializer
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    is_many = isinstance(request.data, list)
    if not is_many:
        return super(ResponseReportFieldsUpdateAPiView, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        ReportResponseSectionField.__dic__.update(request.data)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, headers=headers)
```

serializer :

```
class ReportResponseSectionFieldsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = ReportResponseSectionField
    fields = '__all__'
    depth = 1
```

model:

```
class ReportResponseSectionField(models.Model):                                                                    
description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Descripción')            
report_response_section = models.ForeignKey(ReportResponseSection, related_name='reporte_respuesta_seccion',   
                                            on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)                              
data_type = models.ForeignKey(TypeData, related_name='reporte_respuesta_seccion',                              
                              on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)                                            
require_attachment = models.BooleanField()                                                                     
require_photo = models.BooleanField()                                                                          
mandatory = models.BooleanField()                                                                              
require_scale = models.BooleanField()                                                                          
scale = models.ForeignKey(Scale, related_name='reporte_respuesta_seccion',                                     
                          on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)                                                
response_value = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Respuesta')           
observation = models.TextField('observacion', blank=True, null=True)                                           
                                                                                                               
class Meta:                                                                                                    
    verbose_name = 'Respuestas Partido Seccion Campo'                                                          
    verbose_name_plural = 'Respuestas Partido Secciones Campos'                                                
                                                                                                               
def __str__(self):                                                                                             
    return str(self.description)
```

Conclusion:
Si envio un solo objeto desde el front lo actualiza. Necesito saber como enviar una array de objetos. y actualizar desde el backend la lista de diccionarios. Desde ya gracias.

Siguiendo el consejo de Marco Richetta agregue un nuevo endpoint y me encuentro con un nuevo error.

class ResponseReportFieldListUpdateAPiView(GenericAPIView):

```
def put(self, request):
    # Obtener el  JSON.
    data = request.data

    # Obtener los datos de la base de datos
    emp = ReportResponseSectionField.objects.all()
    # Es necesario pasarlo a listas
    _arr_field = [entry for entry in emp]

    # Serializar los datos
    se = serializers.AddListFieldsSerializer(instance=_arr_field, data=data, many=True)

    # validar y guardar
    if se.is_valid():
        se.save()
        payload = {
            'codigo': status.HTTP_200_OK,
            'mensaje': 'Ok',
            'data': se.data
        }
    else:
        payload = {
            'codigo': status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            'mensaje': 'Fallo',
            'data': se.errors
        }

    return Response(payload, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

y mis nuevos serializers:

class UpdateFieldsSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
""" Recibe dos listas para comparar los datos """

```
class Meta:
    model = ReportResponseSectionField
    fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        # instance = valor original (de la bd)
        # validated_data = valor a comparar
        mapping = {f.id: f for f in instance}
        data_mapping = {item['id']: item for item in validated_data}

        # Realizamos las creaciones si no se encuentran en data_mapping,
        # y las actualizaciones si se encuentran keys en data_mapping
        ret = []
        for _id, data in data_mapping.items():
            field = mapping.get(_id, None)
            if field is None:
                ret.append(self.child.create(data))  # Si no se encuentra se crea
            else:
                ret.append(self.child.update(field, data))  # Se se encuentra se actualiza

        return ret
```

class AddListFieldsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
id = serializers.IntegerField()

```
class Meta:
    list_serializer_class = UpdateFieldsSerializer  # list_serializer_class , nos sirve para trabajar con varios objetos en forma de listas, util para Insert, Update, Delete
```

Me da el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "/home/maximiliano/.pyenv/versions/my_virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/maximiliano/.pyenv/versions/my_virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/maximiliano/.pyenv/versions/my_virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/maximiliano/.pyenv/versions/my_virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/maximiliano/.pyenv/versions/my_virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/maximiliano/.pyenv/versions/my_virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/home/maximiliano/.pyenv/versions/my_virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
File "/home/maximiliano/.pyenv/versions/my_virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/maximiliano/Documentos/WORKSPACE-LPF/BACKEND/backend/saf/apps/informes_auditorias/views.py", line 71, in put
se.save()
File "/home/maximiliano/.pyenv/versions/my_virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 723, in save
self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
File "/home/maximiliano/.pyenv/versions/my_virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 691, in update
"Serializers with many=True do not support multiple update by "
NotImplementedError: Serializers with many=True do not support multiple update by default, only multiple create. For updates it is unclear how to deal with insertions and deletions. If you need to support multiple update, use a `ListSerializer` class and override `.update()` so you can specify the behavior exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Según la [documentación](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-update), tenés que sobrescribir el método `update` de un `ListSerializer`. Lo bueno es que te tiran ahí mismo un primer approach para hacerlo.

Mi primer approach sería sobrescribir el método .update de tu serializer

- Chequeando de entrada si son varios o no
- Si es uno solo llamas al [`.update`](https://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.serializers/ModelSerializer.html#update) original para la instancia
- Si son varios te fijas que otra cosa podes hacer y después podes reutilizar el .update original o meterle tu lógica para bulk

Encontré [esta librería](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk/blob/master/rest_framework_bulk/drf3/serializers.py#L35=) que implementó un bulk update pero quedó bastante obsoleta.

Comment: muchas gracias marcos, segui tu idea y creo que estoy mas cerca pero nuevamente recibo un error. edite la pregunta con las nuevas modificaciones. tal vez vos te das cuenta.